# how to create property method in swift

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, swift

I make one `UITableView` property in my class and make getter method for it like this:

```
@interface SideViewController : UIViewController <UITableViewDataSource,UITableViewDelegate>
@property (nonatomic,strong) UITableView *table;
@end


@implementation SideViewController
@synthesize selectedIndex;
- (void)viewDidLoad {
  [super viewDidLoad];
  self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
}
- (UITableView*)table {
  if (!_table) {
    CGRect tableFrame = CGRectMake(0,150,230, self.view.frame.size.height-150);
    _table = [[UITableView alloc]initWithFrame:tableFrame style:UITableViewStylePlain];
    _table.scrollEnabled = NO;
    _table.delegate = self;
    _table.dataSource = self;
    _table.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = YES;
    _table.separatorInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0, 0);
    [_table setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
    _table.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone;
  }
  return _table;
}
```

when I call `self.table` get my table now I want write this code in swift but I'm so confused!!!
please guide me about that.
this is my swift code :

```
import UIKit

class SideViewController: UIViewController,UITableViewDelegate {

  let table:UITableView = UITableView()

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()

  }


  override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
  }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `lazy` in swift:

```
class SideViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate {

    lazy var table: UITableView = {
        let tableFrame = CGRectMake(0, 150, 230, self.view.frame.size.height - 150)
        let _table = UITableView(frame: tableFrame, style: UITableViewStyle.Plain)
        _table.scrollEnabled = false
        _table.delegate = self
        _table.dataSource = self
        _table.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = true
        _table.separatorInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0, 0)
        _table.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
        _table.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyle.None
        return _table
    }()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
    }

}
```

Comment: No, just like a function, in the class itself

Comment: I updated my answer please check how it will looks like in your class

Comment: as you wish, it is as usual var, with the only difference that its inner closure evaluates only once